# Kotlin basic program is not working in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I have recently installed Android studio 4.1.1. I am getting below error while executing "Hello world" kotlin program in android studio. kindly help me..

- Where:
  Initialization script 'C:\Users\pcadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\KotlinBasicsKt_main__.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:KotlinBasicsKt.main()'.
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
16:25:40: Task execution finished 'KotlinBasicsKt.main()'.

Comment: I believe this happens when computer user name has a space in it. is `pcadmin` the real user name on your windows? if it has any characters other than letters, try changing it to all letters